# ASP.NET MVC: Load PartialView Only Once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

We are using ASP.NET MVC 4 and KO (KnockOutJS) for frontend side.

For making components in KO, we are using ASP.NET MVC partial views (consist of script and template).

Some of our components depend on another component so we load some partials in another partial view to make sure dependent component exists in page.

The problem is that in such cases multiple instance of one partial load in page.

Is there any way to tell the view engine to load every partial only once in each page?

Any idea will appreciated ...

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that multiple partial views include the same partial view, therefore that partial view is rendered multiple times?

Comment: Yes. @BrunoPfohl